# Task scheduler recommendation/advice

Tags: control, ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am looking for some advise on choosing a way/tool to achieve high level control (or say tasks scheduling) with ros. I am naturally more inclined to using scripting (e.g. in python as naturally it integrates with ros) because I have been programming for years and I am convinced of the versatility of languages.

Though I was wondering whether there were other solutions that you would recommend based on experience (e.g. solutions that improve workflow, are more something-friendly... and do not limit the expressive power)

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195818/task-scheduler-recommendation/advice/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-10-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Straight-forward scripting with actionlib interfaces works. If that is sufficient for your goals depends on the task at hand.

The standard ROS way is probably to use [Smach](http://wiki.ros.org/smach), which builds on the concept of state machines

There is a [task planning architecture](http://wiki.ros.org/symbolic_planning?distro=groovy) developed by our group, although I consider that experimental. There might also be other solutions in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-10-24**:
Hum, if Smach is as standard as I expect it to be that may well be a no brainer... Thanks ;)

**Comment by [dmkarage](https://answers.ros.org/users/31032/dmkarage/) on 2018-09-25**:
Could actionlib be used also for different tasks such as navigation and manipulation? For example, patrolling around in a room and once you spot small objects on the ground, pick them up, place them on a table and continue patrolling. Can a behavior like this be implemented with actionlib?